# AndEngine creating a rectangle crashes app

Tags: android, button, andengine, rectangles, touch-event

This is my first time using AndEngine and when I try to create a Rectangle, it crashes right on that line. I'm trying to use the Rectangles for buttons to move the player left or right. I found a tutorial here for the buttons: http://www.matim-dev.com/creating-leftright-game-controller-buttons.html. I even tried using a touch event for the Scene and it crashed there instead. I searched for answers for a long time but still couldn't find an answer so now I am completely stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
HUD controller = new HUD();
    Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, (screenWidth / 2), (screenHeight), getVertexBufferObjectManager()) // It crashes right on this line.
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent touchEvent, float X, float Y)
        {
            // Move left
            if (touchEvent.isActionDown())
            {
                isLeftTouched = true;
            }
            if (touchEvent.isActionUp())
            {
                isLeftTouched = false;
                player1.stop();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onManagedUpdate(float secondsElapsed)
        {
            if (isLeftTouched)
            {
                // Execute your actions.
                player1.moveLeft();

            }
            super.onManagedUpdate(secondsElapsed);
        }
    };

    Rectangle right = new Rectangle(screenWidth / 2, 0, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight, getVertexBufferObjectManager())
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent touchEvent, float X, float Y)
        {
            // Move right
            if (touchEvent.isActionDown())
            {
                isRightTouched = true;
            }
            if (touchEvent.isActionUp())
            {
                isRightTouched = false;
                player1.stop();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onManagedUpdate(float secondsElapsed)
        {
            if (isRightTouched)
            {
                // Execute your actions.
                player1.moveRight();
            }
            super.onManagedUpdate(secondsElapsed);
        }
    };

    controller.registerTouchArea(left);
    controller.registerTouchArea(right);
    controller.attachChild(left);
    controller.attachChild(right);

    camera.setHUD(controller);
```

Here is the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2440):    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable  to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.teej1410.glider/  com.teej1410.glider.MainActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2440):    at  com.teej1410.glider.MainActivity.createControllers(MainActivity.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2440):    at  com.teej1410.glider.MainActivity.onCreateOther(MainActivity.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2440):    at  com.teej1410.glider.MainActivity.onCreateEngineOptions(MainActivity.java:   51)
W/ActivityManager(  434):   Force   finishing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.  I had the Rectangles being created in a separate method which I was calling too early.